# request.security getting different value when changing timeframe

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to collect stochastic rsi 100 and 0 values in an array and use it for  a strategy(or an indicator). I am having trouble getting a fixed value for it on timeframes. It works okay when I use the same time frame as collecting timeframe but when I change it to lower time frame on the live chart, it does not collect a correct value. This example below only gets right data when the timeframe is Month but not on lower ones like week or day.
Can someone help resolve this issue?

```
//@version=5 
indicator(title="test", shorttitle="test", format=format.price, precision=2, overlay=true) 
// general options
displayMonthlySto = input(true, "Show Monthly Stoch", group="General Options")

// options for monthly stoRSI
smoothKMon = input.int(3, "K", minval=1, group="Monthly Time Frame Options") 
smoothDMon = input.int(3, "D", minval=1, group="Monthly Time Frame Options") 
lengthRSIMon = input.int(14, "RSI Length", minval=1, group="Monthly Time Frame Options") 
lengthStochMon = input.int(14, "Stochastic Length", minval=1, group="Monthly Time Frame Options") 
srcMon = input(close, title="RSI Source", group="Monthly Time Frame Options") 
rsi1Mon = ta.rsi(srcMon, lengthRSIMon) 
kMon = ta.sma(ta.stoch(rsi1Mon, rsi1Mon, rsi1Mon, lengthStochMon), smoothKMon) 
dMon = ta.sma(kMon, smoothDMon) 

// timeframe for month
stoMonth = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", kMon)

// initialize arrys for stoch
var sto100MonArr = array.new_float() 
var sto0MonArr = array.new_float()

// collect sto100 and 0 data
if ta.change(time_close("1M")) and displayMonthlySto
    if stoMonth == 100 
        array.push(sto100MonArr, close)
    if stoMonth == 0
        array.push(sto0MonArr, close)

plot(array.size(sto100MonArr)>0 ? array.get(sto100MonArr, array.size(sto100MonArr)-1) : na)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request.security gives inconsistent results when loading lower TF data
For Lower TF data, you must use: [https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_request{dot}security_lower_tf](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_request%7Bdot%7Dsecurity_lower_tf)

This function returns an array of lower TF values

For a locked bigger TF value, you can try this

```
stoMonth = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", kMon[1], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

Comment: Thanks for it but it is for higher timeframe. let's say the current time frame is W or D and the result does not give right one except when it is M timeframe. It seems that it is getting the close value from the first current chart timeframe bar of each month which is not what I am looking for. I would like to get a fixed value regardless of the current chart time frame. I am thinking I have to find a way to locate the last bar on the current chart's time frame for each month and get close value from it and haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: Got it
Try this, that's the way to get a locked higher TF value 
stoMonth = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", kMon[1], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)

Comment: great. Thanks. that worked for the current time frame. but actually it does not seem that it is one I was looking for.  if I apply this to Binance:BTCUSDT, I want to see 58740.55 which is the last stochastic rsi 100 on a month timeframe but I am seeing 60002.43 on a weekly timeframe chart. though it is the last week of a month, if the end of the week is not the last day of the month, the value would be different.. not sure how to solve this so I can get the same value that I can see from the month timeframe chart.

Comment: Got it
Try to play with those two parameters from the request.security function
barmerge.gaps_off and barmerge.lookahead_off

Setting them at both off or both on or only one of them on/off and see if that changes anything

Try also doing that while using kMon[1] in a first time, and then using kMon in a second time

I think one of those combinations should give the results you're expecting

Comment: playing around with what you said, having those below seem to give the best result so far. I will accept this as an answer. Thanks Daveatt.
stoMonth = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", kMon, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
if ta.change(time_close("1M"))
    if stoMonth[1] == 100 and stoMonth != 100
        array.push(sto100MonArr, close[1])
    if stoMonth[1] == 0 and stoMonth != 0
        array.push(sto0MonArr, close[1])

Answer (score 0):

It gives more accurate result if you calculate every thing inside the request.security function, like this one is my example that worked for me. It gives same result for different time frames..

```
request.security(
  syminfo.tickerid,
  '15',
  ta.sma(ta.stoch(
    ta.rsi(close, lengthRSI),
    ta.rsi(close, lengthRSI),
    ta.rsi(close, lengthRSI),
    lengthStoch
  ), smoothK),
  barmerge.gaps_off,
  barmerge.lookahead_on
)
```